# Css selector: first/last-of-type and has another class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In a simple pager I'm building I need to apply specific style to the current page if the current page is the first or the last page. And I don't know how to use the `:first-of-type`/ `:last-of-type` selector in addition to the normal class selector.

```
   <div id="myPages">
      <div class="something-else"></div>
      <div class="page-number current-page">1</div>
      <div class="page-number">2</div>
      <div class="page-number">3</div>
      <div class="another-one"></div>
  </div>
```

I'd like something like `#myPages .page-number:first-of-type.current-page` but it does not work because of the `something-else` and  `another-one` div.

In my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bd21cxab/6/) for example, I'd like the '1' to be blue.

Thanks for your help.

[edit] I've updated the fiddle, I think it's the best way to get my idea :)

Comment: Pseudo-classes select elements, not classes of elements. Adding a class to the mix makes it act more like a filter and it then becomes more restrictive.

Comment: yes, but I don't think it exists a `last-of-class` feature in CSS

Comment: Please check to see if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/bd21cxab/2/

Comment: I've updated my fiddle so you get the idea because what you suggest unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: @Valentin Coudert: Sounds like you've answered your own question, then, since you know no such feature exists?

Comment: (I meant the `last-of-class` selector and was hoping for a way of achieving the same result with a combination of other selectors)

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** As the post author has changed their question, I've updated my answer:

```css
#explain {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#myPages .something-else+.current-page {
  color: blue;
}

#myPages div:nth-last-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="explain">
  Please note:<br> - there will be only one 'page-number' with 'current-page' in my app<br> - I don't know in advance how many pages there will be (so nth-child cannot work)
</div>
<div id="myPages">
  <div class="something-else"></div>
  <div class="page-number current-page">1 - Should be blue because it is the first page-number <strong>and</strong> it has the current-page class</div>
  <div class="page-number">2</div>
  <div class="page-number current-page">3 - Nothing should happen</div>
  <div class="page-number current-page">4 - Should be red because it is the last page-number <strong>and</strong> it has the current-page class</div>
  <div class="another-one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this does what he wants, as your selectors aren't selecting nth-of-items-with-this-class, but items with this class which are also the nth child of their parent, regardless of class. Hence 1 being colored blue instead of 2.

Comment: I don't know the number of page in advance, and I don't where the `current-page` will be

Comment: @ValentinCoudert, I've updated my answer. Is this what you're looking for?